# Has break on cross DB connection

Tags: laravel, eloquent

- Laravel Version: #.#.# 8.18.1
- PHP Version: #.#.# 7.4
- Database Driver & Version: MySQL 5.7.32

#### Description:

Had two models (menu, service) with two different databases, connection set in model. when I get menu model with (service) relation, it's working fine. But when used `has(service)` to get the menu which have service will shown
`Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'common.services' doesn't exist`

it will look in my first database

common is my first database name and services are store in second database.

#### Steps to Reproduce:

create two model in different database
fetch `menu` with relation `has(service)` to get only menu which have service

Comment: Provide some code sample to reproduce the situation/error

Comment: could u share this repo...so I can see...I try everything.. it's strange error only shown when I used has()........ with() work fine

Comment: Sorry my bad, you are right doesn't work for `has()` but works very well with `with()`

Comment: there are few other pitfalls with laravel and multiple databases, i.e. you cant create a record in DB A when parent model is in DB B. Laravel has two methods responsible for decoration of table name, one appends (the one that is used for with() and similar) appends db name, but the second one (the main method) it only appends a name prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Documentation

From [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) :

> Eloquent does not currently support querying for relationship
> existence across databases. The relationships must exist within the
> same database.

## QueryBuilder VS Eloquent

What Cause success retrieve on `with()` and failure on `has()` ?

### QueryBuilder crosses Databases

with() has been implemented in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder` and collects relations in `$eagerLoading` array to load with query.

### Relation has not implement cross Database Feature

but has() is in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\QueriesRelationships` trait and adopted in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` calls `getRelationWithoutConstraints()` which is :

```
/**
     * Get the "has relation" base query instance.
     *
     * @param  string  $relation
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
     */
    protected function getRelationWithoutConstraints($relation)
    {
        return Relation::noConstraints(function () use ($relation) {
            return $this->getModel()->{$relation}();
        });
    }
```

as PHPDoc says, its just getting **base query instance** for **has relation** .
its a simple method JUST creating a simple **Base Query** based on `getModel()` query (parent query) and add it.

The solution can be achieve using `DB::raw`.

Comment: yeah you were right... I didn't read this RED block

but you can also achieve this Model::first()->relation()->first()....sound stupid but work